# Is there a rule for when the suffix -ian is one syllable long, when two?

Tags: pronunciation, suffixes

A question from my student:

> I'm rather confused how many syllables in the words with suffix -ian? Some words like 'e-lec-tri-cian, mu-si-cian, A-sian' have only one syllable while ' veg-e-tar-i-an, co-me-di-an, his-to-ri-an' have two. Is there any rule for this or just memorize them?

In her examples, the first set is stressed on the second-to-last syllable, the second set on the third-to-last.  But how can we know the difference?

Comment: Perhaps they need to look the words up in dictionaries. One pattern I can observe (while reading this question) is that the last syllable seems to always be either /shən/ or /zhən/ in your first group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say a good rule of thumb is to look at the base form of the word.

If the base form of the word ends in a "y," then a noun form ending in "-ian" will generally be pronounced as two syllables. Intuitively, these words have a hard time losing that "ee" sound. For example:

- comedy => comedian
- custody => custodian
- history => historian
- library => librarian
- ovary => ovarian

If the base form of the word ends in a "c" or "g" (velar stops), then that originally hard "k" or "g" sound becomes "sh" or "j" respectively in front of the front vowel "i" of "-ian" and is pronounced as a single syllable (a form of *elision*). A similar transformation can happen for words that already end in "s" or "sh" sounds. For example:

- clinic => clinician
- cosmetic => cosmetician
- magic => magician
- theology => theologian
- Venice => Venetian

If the base form ends in most other consonants or vowels other than "y", then the "-ian" ending cannot be elided with the final consonant/vowel into a single syllable, and thus is pronounced as two syllables. In the case of final vowels, an infix "-n-" is generally used to separate the final vowel from the "-ian" ending. For example:

- guard => guardian
- pluto => plutonian

Finally, examples like "Asian" are in fact a slightly different construct, wherein the suffix "-n" is used to make an adjective. Words that would be confusing in this regard because they end in "-ian" include:

- Asia => Asian [one-syllable "-ian"]
- mammal => mammalian [two-syllable "-ian"] (here the root is really the Latin "mammalia" which is the term used for the Class of mammals)

Comment: good answer but theology -> theologian goes in the first set as it ends in y

Comment: I should have elaborated. "Theology" represents an exception to the "-y" rule of thumb, but belongs in this second group of examples because the "-ian" suffix is pronounced as one syllable.

Comment: that is incorrect, theologian is pronounced with with two syllables.

Comment: That is not correct. Theologian is pronounced /θiəˈloʊdʒən/, syllables broken down to the-o-lo-gian. As a native speaker I can confirm this, and you can refer to the [Wiktionary entry for theologian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/theologian) as confirmation.

Comment: as a fellow native speaker, i have to disagree with both you and your wiki

Comment: In case someone is left with any doubt about the only accepted pronunciation: [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/theologian?q=theologian) specifies /THēəˈlōjən/, [Merriam Webster's Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theologian) specifices \thē-ə-ˈlō-jən\, as two fairly reputable sources of pronunciation. Nothing personal, but there's not a lot of wiggle room or any alternative pronunciations for this word, as there are for many English words.

Comment: I would go with @semperos here, but it's interesting that native speakers can disagree about individual words.

Comment: Accepting this comment since my student told me she preferred it.  The other is also insightful though.

Answer (score 5):

A rather reliable rule of thumb is as follows, although there are always exceptions.

The letters *-(i)an* in these endings are pronounced as -/ən/, so as one syllable:

> -sian
>   -cian
>   -tian
>   -gian

So it depends on the letter that comes before *-ian*. Other *-ian* endings are pronounced as -/ɪən/ (two syllables) or -/jən/: the difference between these two pronunciations is often hard to hear.

Another way to put it is as follows. If the sound of the preceding consonant changes because of the *-i-*, that means *-ian* should be pronounced in a way where you can't hear *-i-* as a separate sound. So if *-s-* is pronounced as /ʒ/ rather than /s/ or /z/, *-sian* is pronounced as -/ʒən/. The same applies if *-c-* is pronounced as /ʃ/ rather than /s/ (→ -/ʃən/), or if *-t-* is pronounced as /ʃ/ rather than /t/ (→ -/ʃən/). This does not apply to *-g-*, though.

The same rule usually applies to *-ion, -ial, -ious,* and similar suffixes with *-i-[vowel]-*, mutatis mutandis.

---

Legend for the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet):

- ʃ  = *sh* as in English *sheep*
- ʒ  = *j* as in **French** *jeu*, and *-si-* as in English *Asian*
- ə  = *a* as in English *an*, and *e* as in *the* (the sound is called *schwa*)

Comment: So the difference is really between words where the elision of –i- is optional (like historian) and those where it’s required (like magician).  The learner would need to focus on how the final consonant in the base changes – being unsure about this means he or she will likely fall back on the reading pronounciation (–ian as two syllables).  Thanks!